# Open 3 views on 3 buttons

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

[image: /Users/harshalbajaj/Desktop/iOS Simulator Screen shot Apr 2, 2014, 7.14.40 PM.png]

I have 3 buttons on same page but those buttons are calling 3 different views on
click.Like button1 opens view1,button2 open view2 and button3 open view3.but i want all
those buttons on upside of view like tab bar is having downside.I tried by creating or
 calling views on button click but on every click it's creating new object of view which i
 don't want..Please help me to solve this issue.Is there any other way to solve this
 problem. I tried segment too but not working.

Comment: Hey chaaruu, could you provide additional information: Is the same ViewController taking care of the button-clicks? Are there on these 3 views added to always the same view?

Comment: why dont you assign the views to instance variables and store them. so the next time you press button you can check if variable is nil & return it if its created earlier.

Comment: In this three button Click action you want to load 3 different view or ViewController?

Comment: @VineeshTP Yes. but when i did code for this it's creating problem because on every click it's creating new object.Please give me solution in code. so, i will understand.

Comment: @nsuinteger I am not that much master in IOS.I am still learning. So, can you give me any example to solve this problem.

Comment: are you using storyBoard ? and you want to display View or ViewController?

Comment: @VineeshTP I am using both storyboard and xib's.

Comment: In storyboard don't mix with Xib.

Comment: you want to display View or ViewController?

Comment: @VineeshTP I don't have other option because at some point when i am calling any view on other view..I am getting black screen..so, when i am using xib..I got solved my problem..

Comment: If difficulty to handle, user Container and switch views/viewController as per button click.

Comment: @VineeshTP any other solution to solve my issue.

Comment: If you are using continer class  and switch views you can handle easly with out any crash.  Be careful when you switch to view/View controller remove the previous and add new.

Comment: Don't mix with storyboard and xib it will affect performance of your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure, if this is what you really want.

The view would be larger than it actually requires to be, regarding your screenshot?

Why don't you just set the views size to match the size of the view that is below your three buttons.

In case the entire ViewControllers' view is of height: 524px
substracting the orange bar and the buttons: around 450px

Now just create the view from your buttons click action with the exact frame size, as your tableview and add it to the view as subview?
If another button is clicked, remove this view again and add the new view?

So in case you got this in one single ViewController, which I guess:
Simply change the following for your buttons:

---

So, in case you got the following 3 buttons

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonA;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonB;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonC;
```

Implement the function, which reacts on these three button events:

```
- (IBAction)myButtonAction:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIViewController *viewControllerToDisplay;

    // Load UIViewController for its view from your .xib-file:
    // Alternatively you could do this with switch.case and checking a button's tag-values, but I think is easier to read
    if (sender == self.buttonA)      viewControllerToDisplay = [ViewControllerA new];
    else if (sender == self.buttonB) viewControllerToDisplay = [ViewControllerB new];
    else if (sender == self.buttonC) viewControllerToDisplay = [ViewControllerC new];

    // Only display the view, if the viewController was created
    if (viewControllerToDisplay)
    {
        viewControllerToDisplay.view.frame = self.tableView.frame;
        [self.view addSubview:viewControllerToDisplay];
    }
}
```

Comment: I already think about it but still i am not sure it will work or not.. because i already change my design too many times..I am using storyboard and xib's both to develop this app.